# Jquery Validation Plugin - how to add a function for every validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is it possible to do some function for every validation of the fields of the form?
I have enabled the auto focus of the validation plugin but the problem is the function I've created happens before the validation happens.

My function:

```
$("select, input").change(function(){
    alert("example");
});
```

Validation

```
 $(this.initVariables.formId).validate({
        ignore: ":hidden",
        onkeyup: false
    });
```

What I want:

```
Validate
execute My Function
```

What is happening:

```
execute My Function
Validate
```

My GOAL:
Is to determine if to loop all the field to count the number of error messages. If My Function happens before the validation, the error message will not be visible.

Thank you.

Comment: Just [read the documentation for this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)... you have a ton of options and callback functions already available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery validation plugins from this http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Options_for_the_validate.28.29_method

you can use answer in validator section instead of write your own hooks
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/numberOfInvalids

```
// Displays a summary of invalid fields after a invalid submit.
var validator = $("#myform").validate({
  invalidHandler: function() {
    $("#summary").text(validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid");
  }
});
```

hope this help